# Given the density of water and the gravitational force of the earth, calculate the force

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

So I'm taking calculus 2, having never taken physics and I'm having some trouble understanding the problems we are at.

I'm trying use integrals to calculate the force required to pump a container of water.

So far my teacher states that given the density of water $\rho = 1000\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}$ and the gravitational acceleration of the earth $g = 0.8\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$ we can determine that $1\ \mathrm m^3$ weighs $1000\ \mathrm g$ which is around $9800\ \mathrm N$.

I can't seem to figure out how he got to $9800\ \mathrm N$.

I'm trying to play with the density of water and the gravitational acceleration to get to 9800, but my units don't seem to add up.

Comment: Might be a typo. $g=9.8m/s^2$

Answer (score 0):

Well the force of gravity is equal to $mg=\rho V g=(1000 kg/m^3)(1 m^3)(9.8kg *m/s^2)=9800N$.

Comment: The way I see the units add up is (Kg/m^3)(m/s^2) shouldn't that give (Kg) / (m^2 * s^2)

I'm lost with how you multiply density and gravity and end up with Newtons that are (Kg)(m/s^2)

Comment: You forgot to multiply by the volume: the units would be (kg/m^3)(m^3)(m/s^2)=(kg m/s^2) for density * volume * acceleration = force.

Comment: Rather than $9.8kg *m/s^2$ it should just be $9.8\,\mathrm m/\mathrm s^2$ so you don't end up with $\mathrm{kg}^2$.